# Two select list with next/previous buttons

Tags: jquery

My select list with next and previous button is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/3q9uF/). My two independent list is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/mG959/), when I select any option from first list and after select any option from second list my first list will be reset. I would like to combine the two examples and get two list with unique next/previous button. When the first list is active to use the buttons move through it, and when the second list is active to using the same buttons move through it.
Is it possible?

Terafor and Mahesh, thank you for answer, but when I select any from second list next and previous button are disabled.

```
$('#second').change(function () {
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == 'a','b') {
    $('#first').val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include *all* relevant code in the SO question and not only in external links (jsfiddles are a great complement so please keep them).

Comment: and when both lists are active?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible! You just have to remember which list has focus and then use that in buttons navigation;

http://jsfiddle.net/KZFcb/ //edit: link correction

```
var isInFocus;
$('select').focus(function(){
   isInFocus = $(this);
});
```

What you have to add is logic to disable buttons correctly when element gains focus.

Comment: Terafor, when I select option 14 in first list, and select any in second list the next button is disabled. And, when I select any in second list my first list not reset (returns to "Choose an option..."). Is it possible that the first list has, for example, 14 items, and second that has 9 items.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="first" class="dropdown">
<option value="">Choose an option...</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
<option value="6">Option 6</option>
<option value="7">Option 7</option>
<option value="8">Option 8</option>
<option value="9">Option 9</option>
<option value="10">Option 10</option>
<option value="11">Option 11</option>
<option value="12">Option 12</option>
<option value="13">Option 13</option>
<option value="14">Option 14</option> 
       </select>
<hr>

     <select id="second" class="dropdown">
<option value="">Choose an option...</option>
<option value="a">Option a</option>
<option value="b">Option b</option>
<option value="c">Option c</option>
<option value="d">Option d</option>
<option value="e">Option e</option>
<option value="f">Option f</option>
<option value="g">Option g</option>
<option value="h">Option h</option>
<option value="i">Option i</option>
<option value="j">Option j</option>
<option value="k">Option k</option>
<option value="l">Option l</option>
<option value="m">Option m</option>
<option value="n">Option n</option> 
       </select>
    <hr>
<button id="prev" class="prevbutton">Previous</button>
<button id="next" class="nextbutton">Next</button>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#first').on('change', function(){
       $('select').removeClass('activeList');
        $(this).addClass('activeList');
    });
    $('#second').on('change', function(){
       $('select').removeClass('activeList');
        $(this).addClass('activeList');
    });

    $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });

    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        $(this).find('option').last().attr({'data-last' : 'lastList'});

        if ($('.activeList').val() == 0) {
          $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
        } else if ($('option:selected', this).attr('data-last') === 'lastList') {
            $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });
        } else {
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
          $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: false });
        }
    });
    $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });

    $("#next").click(function() {

      var nextElement = $('.activeList > option:selected').next('option');

      if (nextElement.length > 0) {
        $('.activeList > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
      $('.activeList').trigger('change');      
      }
    });

    $("#prev").click(function() {
      var nextElement = $('.activeList > option:selected').prev('option');
      if (nextElement.length > 0) {
        $('.activeList > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
      $('.activeList').trigger('change');        
      }  
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Mahesh, when I select option 14 in first list, and select any in second list the next button is disabled. Is it possible that the first list has, for example, 14 items, and second that has 9 items.

Comment: Please try with the above jQuery part.. i hope that works http://jsfiddle.net/mG959/3/